# Passing argument to custom annoymous jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery live search from https://github.com/rpheath/searchbox.
I got multiple search boxes in one page. What I want is passing an argument `param` to the jquery anonymous function so that the settings' can be directed to different url.

```
$('#input1').searchbox("action1");
$('#input2').searchbox("action2");
```

I tried to modified the code like this but the `param` always return undefined. What is the right way to modify the code?

The JS code:

```
(function($, param) {
$.searchbox = {}

$.extend(true, $.searchbox, {
settings: {
  url: '/Home/'+param,
  param: 'searchString',
  dom_id: '#'+param,
  delay: 100,
  loading_css: '#loading'
},

loading: function() {
  $($.searchbox.settings.loading_css).show()
},

// other codes omitted

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass `param` as a separate parameter to be concatenated to `url`?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes that's what I want to do!

Comment: @Matt, it won't work. You have to change the logic of the plugin. It uses a single *(global)* setting for all searchboxes. So, every change to the url of one searchbox will apply to all searchboxes.

Comment: @Thomas so the only way I could do is making separate js files with different function name for each search box?

Comment: That might work, but is a pretty poor solution. Better rewrite the code to support multiple instance with distinct settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tried the plugin, though you should be able to modify the expected parameters at lines `51` and `52` of source

```
  $.fn.searchbox = function(config, param) {
    var settings = $.extend(true, $.searchbox.settings, config || {});
    if (param) settings.url = settings.url + param;
```

Comment: this will modify `$.searchbox.settings.url` for all searchboxes. This plugin is basically a singleton.

Comment: @Thomas Have not tried plugin. Not sure what action plugin actually performs. What action does plugin perform? If this is case, and if necessary, would suggest OP re-write entire plugin to create a pattern which does not modify all instances of plugin.

Comment: @guest271314 I'm trying your idea anyway but the `param` is still undefined. `$('#input1').searchbox("action1");` is this the correct way to pass the parameter to the function?

Comment: The documentation indicates an object is expected to be passed to `.searchbox()`